# Constructing an algebraic surface with singularities on the unit circle.

Tags: integration, functions, algebraic-geometry

I am currently doing a project on algebraic surfaces, and I want to construct an algebraic surface $\mathbb{V}(f(x, y, z))$ that exhibit its singularities on the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$.

#### My attempt thus far:

For any point $p \in \mathbb{V}(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ we want the following:

- $f(p) = 0$,
- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p) = 0$.

It's been a few years since I did any integration and my abilities in that area feel lackluster.

Any help is greatly appreciated.